# Is it possible to detect the accurate original pixel density by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to determine the pixel density of my user's browser.

It seems `window.devicePixelRatio` works well, however, if the user zooms the browser, the value might be inaccurate, according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049175/can-devicepixelratio-be-less-than-1) on SO.

Is there any way that I can tell the pixel density no matter whether a user zooms in/out his/her browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are best practices for detecting pixel ratio/density?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541676/what-are-best-practices-for-detecting-pixel-ratio-density)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I used the function `getDevicePixelRatio` in the latest answer to that question but will get different results in different zooming levels.